# How can I style the days which aren't in the current month differently in my Vue Calendar component?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

edit: I guess the problem is in the 'off' class rule, but couldn't solve yet.

I'm trying to fix my company vue calendar component.
I didn't done that, just doing maintenance in the system and found this strange behavior.

The current rules in this calendar component makes it doesn't show 2021 months until the "first" (from the left) is also 2021. Maybe the empty line in november could be related to, IDK.
(I tried to withdraw everything that I considered not directly related to the months/years relation, but if necessary I can edit).

Could someone help me, please? :)

[part 2020/part 2021 calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTjt8.png)

[all 2021 calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vT87i.png)

```
//template

  <tr v-for="(dateRow, index) in calendar(mes)" :key="index">
    <slot name="date-slot" v-for="(date, idx) in dateRow">
      <td
        :class="dayClass(date, mes)"
        @click="dateClick(date)"
        @mouseover="hoverDate(date)"
        :key="`${idx}-${mes}`"
      >
        <p>{{ date.getDate() }}</p>
      </td>
    </slot>
  </tr>
```

```
//script

    calendar(index) {
      let add = index - 1;
      let month = this.month + add;
      let year = this.currentMonthDate.getFullYear();
      let firstDay = new Date(year, month - 1, 1);
      let lastMonth = firstDay.getMonth() - 1;
      let daysInLastMonth = new Date(year, month - 1, 0).getDate();
      let dayOfWeek = firstDay.getDay();
      let calendar = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        calendar[i] = [];
      }
      let startDay = daysInLastMonth - dayOfWeek + 1;
      if (startDay > daysInLastMonth) startDay -= 7;
      let curDate = new Date(year, lastMonth, startDay, 12, 0, 0);
      for (
        let i = 0, col = 0, row = 0;
        i < 6 * 7;
        i++, col++, curDate.setDate(curDate.getDate() + 1)
      ) {
        if (i > 0 && col % 7 === 0) {
          col = 0;
          row++;
        }
        calendar[row][col] = new Date(curDate.getTime());
      }
      return calendar;
    },


    dayClass(date, index) {
      let add = index - 1;
      let dt = new Date(date);

      dt.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

      let start = new Date();
      let end = new Date();

      let in_range = false;
      let index_range_date = 0;

      this.dateRanges.forEach((r, index) => {
        if (r.start && r.end) {
          let startAux = new Date(r.start);
          startAux.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

          let endAux = new Date(r.end);
          endAux.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

          if (dt >= startAux && dt <= endAux) {
            in_range = true;
            index_range_date = index;

            start = startAux;
            start.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

            end = endAux;
            end.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
          }
        }
      });

      let classes = {
        off: dt.getMonth() + 1 !== this.month + add,
        weekend: date.getDay() === 6 || date.getDay() === 0,
        today: dt.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0) == new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0),
        active:
          dt.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0) == new Date(this.start).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0) ||
          dt.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0) == new Date(this.end).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0),
        "start-date": dt.getTime() === start.getTime(),
        "end-date": dt.getTime() === end.getTime()
        // 'disabled': dt <= new Date()
      };

      classes["in-range-" + index_range_date.toString()] = in_range;
      classes["hover-" + this.empty_range.toString()] = true;

      return classes;
    },
    checkYear() {
      if (this.$refs.yearSelect !== document.activeElement) {
        this.$nextTick(() => {
          this.year_text = this.currentMonthDate.getFullYear();
        });
      }
    },
```

Comment: if you don't want them to appear, simply don't put them there in the first place - i.e. if `curDate.getMonth() !== month` set `calendar[row][col] = null` or something, then in your component HTML handle this case using a v-if most likely - you haven't shown the HTML part of the component so, can't help

Comment: Personally, I think your logic is slightly flawed ... why is there a whole week, a full 7 days, of October in November? also `year += (this.month + add) % 12;` looks problematic ... I think if the first month is December 2020, you'd end up with January 2021 then February 2022

Comment: Did you know, `new Date(2020,12,1)` will give you January 1 2021? and `new Date(2020,13,1)` is February 1 2021? That knowledge could help remove a large part of your code

Comment: @Bravo I've found another version in the system for this component. Maybe now it's easier to make it work properly. Could you give it a look again, please?